# Быстрые потокобезопасные Java- коллекции

Tags: java, многопоточность, коллекции, поиск-библиотек

Есть ли библиотеки с конкурентными коллекциями, которые работают быстрее стандартного пакета `java.util.concurrent`? Я пытался найти такую библиотеку, но не нашел. Лично меня интересует потокобезопасный `ArrayList`, который работает быстрее стандартного `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Comment: Если требования к функциональности минимальный - сделайте свой

Comment: Alexander Chernin, если честно, не могу придумать как сделать более быстрый потокобезопасный ArrayList, вот почему и ищу решения

Comment: идея в том, что он будет приспособлен только под вашу задачу и не будет сожежать лишние функции

Comment: а вообще, ArrayList - пока что лучшее, что можно найти

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ни разу не проверял, попробуйте такой способ:

```
Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<?>())
```